# classdefnotfound when referencing a java project on android

Tags: java, android, jvm, noclassdeffounderror, dalvik

I am experiencing what appears to be a unique error when trying to compile my Android project. I am developing for API level 21 (lollipop)

My project references a java project I created previously. The project contains no error.

I have seen there are similar projects that have the same error. I have tried the following to fix the error:

- Moved Android dependencies to first in the orders and export tab.
- Moved the gen folder above the src folder in orders and export.
- Ensured the comipler is set to 1.6.
- Ensured that Google APIs is selected as the build target.
- Ensured the project is added to Projects under Java Build Path
- Ensured all boxes are ticked in order and export.

If I comment out the lines referencing the java library the project works as you'd expect.

I would really appreciate any help on this, I am all out of ideas.

Below is my stack trace:

```
    12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193): Process: com.running.mattboyle.runnertoolbox, PID: 14193
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: common.Parser$1
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at common.Parser.parse(Parser.java:79)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at common.Parser.<init>(Parser.java:54)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at search.Search.<clinit>(Search.java:34)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at routeGeneration.routePlotter.createRoute(routePlotter.java:28)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at com.running.mattboyle.runnertoolbox.RunningMap.getUsersLocation(RunningMap.java:115)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at com.running.mattboyle.runnertoolbox.RunningMap.onCreate(RunningMap.java:59)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-30 21:58:27.841: E/AndroidRuntime(14193):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

EDIT: so I have spent all night messing with this and am really starting to feel like I cannot resolve it. I removed my project from eclipse and reimported it. Removed all dependencies and readded it and I can't seem to find any way to resolve it. If anyone has any insight at l I would really appreciate it.

EDIT 2: after moving things around a bit, I am still getting the above error but also the below. Hopefully it helps solve the problem.

```
01-01 17:09:24.964: I/art(11130): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<src.common.Parser$1>
```

Edit 3: 
Ok I made a slight bit of progress.

I am creating a static object in Java which has an anonymous inner class. That is what the $parser error was. 
I moved the class into a new one called SinkImplementation and created a new object of it. The error message now changed to:

```
`01-01 20:21:33.859: E/AndroidRuntime(32547): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: src.common.SinkImplementation`
```

So for some reason, this class is causing me some issues.  My sinkImplementation class implements Sink which is from a .jar file provided by Open Street Map. The dependencies all seem to be ok and I struggling to get any further with this.

Comment: This looks a bit strange since the class `common.Parser` is obviously found but not the anonymous inner class `common.Parser$1`. Does this happen for a debug or a release build?

Comment: Hi Henry, thanks for the reply. I am using my debug key at the moment.